# What is the time complexity of while loops?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to find the time complexity of while loops and I have no idea where to begin. I understand how to find the complexity class of for loops, but when it comes to while loops, I get completely lost. Any advice/tips on where to begin?

Here is an example of a problem:

```
x = 0;
A[n] = some array of length n;
while (x != A[i]) {
   i++;
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "order of while-loops"?

Comment: This is equivalent to a for loop, looping the index variable ```i``` over the array ```A```.  It has O(n).  Keep in mind that big-O notation denotes the worst possible time taken by the algorithm, and if the desired element is at the end of the array, you will execute the loop ```n``` times, and the loop has a constant cost.  Therefore, you will execute kn operations, for some constant k; therefore, the loop is O(n).

Comment: Guys, this is not a bad question at all. I have seen students who are new to this machinery face this doubt a lot, and I think it is reasonable, especially for someone self taught.

Comment: The question is reasonable, but the wording is very poor.  This can be hard when you're not familiar with the lingo, in this case I guess the OP is looking for help on how to determine the time complexity of a while loop.

Comment: @GuyGreer yes, when I said "order," I meant time complexity. In class, we typically refer to everything as "order" so that's just what I used hear. But, as I mentioned, I meant for it to be taken as the "time complexity" or the "Big-Oh" of the while-loop. My apologies for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you gotta do something `n` times, you have to do it `n` times. You can use a `for` loop, a `while` loop or whatever that your programming language (or pseudo code!)  offers.
Crudely, big O notation comments on the amount of work you have to do, and doesn't care about how you do it (somewhat less crudely, it comments on how the amount of work that needs to be done grows with the growing input).

(More details below)

---

I think you are confusing things here.
`for` and `while` are programming language constructs to express operations that are to be repeated.

Algorithm analysis is agnostic of the language of implementation, and doesn't care about the actual constructs you use while expressing the algorithm.

Consider following:

```
1. Input n
2. Do OperationX n times
```

The Big O notation machinery helps you in commenting on the complexity of the above operation. This helps in many cases. For example, it can help you in comparing the runtime of the operation above with the following:

```
1. Input n
2. Input m
3. Repeat m OperationX n times.
```

The Big O notation will tell you that the former is O(n) and the latter is O(m * n)  (assuming `OperationX` takes a constant time).

You can write the code using the loop construct of your choice, it doesn't matter.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    operationX;
}
```

Is the first operation, and

```
i = j = 0;
while(i < n) {
    j = 0;
    while(j < m) {
      operationX;
      j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

the second. The big O notation doesn't really care if the for and while was switched.

---

```
A[n] = some array of length n;
for(x = 0;x != A[i];i++) {

}
```

Is a `for` re-write of your question with the same complexity (`O(n)`).

Comment: Makes sense. Now, in this specific instance, is it correct to say that the while loop is of O(n), based on what @Eric said above?

Comment: @AlecStewart In the worst case, you might have to traverse the entire array, and thus the complexity is indeed `O(n)`.

Comment: Wow, that makes complete sense now. It's actually a lot simpler than I first thought it would be. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AlecStewart Anytime. Good luck.

Comment: @AlecStewart: Yes, a linear search has `O(n)` complexity, unless the elements are known to be ordered so that the *average* stop position is something less than `n/2`.  e.g. if you're searching for things that were usually recently added to the back of your array (and you search from back to front), the average running time could be O(1), O(log n), or O(sqrt n), or anything else depending on what you can prove about where the target element can be.  You could have something with O(n) worst case but O(1) average case (like adding to a hash table, where adding N elements takes O(N) time).