# Calculating the Time and Space Complexity of Maximum sum of two elements whose digit sum is equal

Tags: java, android, kotlin, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have an interview and i really want to know the space and the time complexity of this problem
I believe that the time complexity of this problem is an O(nlog(n)) but i'm not sure and the space complexity is really hard for me to figure out because it may depend on the input. is this right ?

```
fun maxSumDigits(arr : IntArray) : Int{

        val hashMap : MutableMap<Int,Int> = mutableMapOf()
        var result = -1
        for (element in arr){
            val sumDigit = digitsSum(element)

            if (hashMap.containsKey(sumDigit)){

                result = max(result, hashMap[sumDigit]?.plus(element) ?: 0)

            }
            hashMap[sumDigit] = max(element, hashMap[sumDigit] ?: 0)

        }
        System.out.println(result)
        return result

    }

    private fun digitsSum(num: Int): Int {

        var n = num
        var result = 0

        while (n > 0){
            result += n % 10
            n /= 10
        }
        return result

    }
```

Comment: this might give you some insights https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637125/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-while-loops

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity is expected O(n), which is a little odd.  The size of a machine word is usually considered constant, and `digitSum` takes time proportional to that - O(1).  You do it n times, so it's O(n) for all the sums. The hashmap operations takes O(n) expected time.

The strange thing is that if there was a rule that all of the array elements were between 0 and n, then the worst case for any n would take *less* time, but we would say that the complexity is O(n log n), because `digitSum` would be O(log n) instead of O(1).  Restricting the input makes the summation time depend on n in a logarithmic way.

The space complexity is just O(n) to store the n maximums in the hashmap.